# Thinkpad T400: Suspend to HD doesn't resume

Tags: power-management, suspend, thinkpad

I've got a Thinkpad T400 with Gentoo Linux installed. Suspend-to-RAM works like a charm.

However, Susped-to-Disk doesn't work: if I suspend, the Laptop powers down and accesses the HD for around 30s. However, if I switch it back on, it just boots as normal, but doesn't resume to the previous state.

Here's the `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` just before the suspend:

```
Sun Oct 21 14:16:44 CEST 2012: Finished.
Initial commandline parameters: 
Blacklisting 01grub.
Sun Oct 21 15:26:06 CEST 2012: Running hooks for hibernate.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
Linux rgs-lenovo 3.4.9-gentoo #1 SMP Fri Aug 31 18:55:03 CEST 2012 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
cdc_wdm                 8704  0 
cdc_acm                14890  0 
rfcomm                 21490  0 
bnep                    9782  0 
btusb                  10904  0 
bluetooth             162465  5 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
mmc_block              16408  0 
nls_iso8859_1           4521  0 
nls_cp850               5362  0 
vfat                    8384  0 
fat                    45316  1 vfat
twofish_x86_64_3way    19478  0 
lrw                     3622  1 twofish_x86_64_3way
twofish_x86_64          5539  1 twofish_x86_64_3way
twofish_common         14649  2 twofish_x86_64_3way,twofish_x86_64
aes_x86_64              7768  0 
aes_generic            26983  1 aes_x86_64
xts                     2912  1 twofish_x86_64_3way
gf128mul                7431  2 lrw,xts
dm_crypt               13973  0 
dm_mod                 62853  1 dm_crypt
rndis_host              6143  0 
cdc_ether               4584  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 17584  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
arc4                    1345  2 
sdhci_pci              10056  0 
sdhci                  20883  1 sdhci_pci
firewire_ohci          27077  0 
mmc_core               82856  3 mmc_block,sdhci_pci,sdhci
firewire_core          49742  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t               1635  1 firewire_core
iwlwifi               233406  0 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    43770  1 
mac80211              338064  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              156724  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_hda_intel          22760  4 
snd_hda_codec          88731  2 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_pcm                73911  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_timer              18324  2 snd_pcm
snd_page_alloc          7332  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
loop                   15063  0 
vboxnetflt             12915  0 
vboxdrv              1759366  1 vboxnetflt
fuse                   60817  1 
thinkpad_acpi          64233  0 
snd                    59641  12 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8062552    6417912    1644640          0     427824    4174720
-/+ buffers/cache:    1815368    6247184
Swap:     12582908          0   12582908

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave hibernate hibernate:
Blacklisting 01grub.

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/01grub hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/01grub hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/49bluetooth hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/49bluetooth hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler hibernate hibernate:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler hibernate hibernate: success.
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate:

/usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: success.
Sun Oct 21 15:26:08 CEST 2012: performing hibernate
```

In the `/var/log/syslog` I found  the following line:

```
Oct 21 15:27:10 lenovo kernel: PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

Here's my grub config:

```
title Gentoo Linux
root (hd0,0)
kernel /3.4.9-gentoo root=/dev/sda3 rootfstype=ext4 resume=swap:/dev/sda2 i915.modeset=1 fan_control=1
```

`/dev/sda2` is my swap partition.

What could be wrong?

Comment: IIRC, there's a real_resume option need to be set as well

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing my grub config. The `swap:` in the `resume` parameter is not needed. My config now looks like this:

```
title Gentoo Linux
root (hd0,0)
kernel /3.4.9-gentoo root=/dev/sda3 rootfstype=ext4 resume=/dev/sda2 i915.modeset=1 fan_control=1
```